# Info on cp --preserve=links

Tags: symlink, cp, hard-link

I'm trying to understand what `cp --preserve=links` does when used by itself.

From my tests it seems that it copies a normal file normally and dereferences symlinks, but it seems like it just has the same effect as `cp -L` when used on a single file.

Is that true or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `--preserve=links` option does not refer to symbolic links, but to hard links. It asks `cp` to preserve any existing hard link between two or more files that are being copied.

```
$ date > file1
$ ln file1 file2
$ ls -1i file1 file2
6034008 file1
6034008 file2
```

You can see that the two original files are hard-linked and their inode number is 6034008.

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ cp file1 file2 dir1
$ ls -1i dir1
total 8
6035093 file1
6038175 file2
```

You can see now that without `--preserve=links` their copies have two different inode numbers: there is no longer a hard link between the two.

```
$ mkdir dir2
$ cp --preserve=links file1 file2 dir2
$ ls -1i dir2
total 8
6089617 file1
6089617 file2
```

You can see now that with `--preserve=links`, the two copies are still hard-linked, but their inode number is 6089617, which is not the same as the inode number of the original files (contrary to what `cp --link` would have done).

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting some conflicting information after testing and reading the man page. I just ran some tests and found the following.

```
[root@el7-1 dest]# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Aug 18 16:51 test1.txt -> ../src/test1.txt
```

The following commands all deference the link

```
cp test1.txt test2.txt 
cp -L test1.txt test2.txt 
cp --preserve=link test1.txt test2.txt
```

The following command copies the symlink itself

```
cp -P test1.txt test2.txt
```

Comment: Accorsing to other answers --preserve=links and --no-dereference used together should be used to copy symlinks, but after trying only --no-dereference and --preserve=links and --no-dereference together and running stat on the two links it seems the results are the same.

Comment: I also noticed this. It seems that the man page and other sources (random google results) offer no coherent information.